# Windows API: Undefined reference to DisconnectEx

Tags: c++, c, winapi, mingw, winsock

I'm developing an application that uses windows sockets. My socket class has a method named Disconnect that uses DisconnectEx, but i get the following error at linking time:

```
undefined reference to `DisconnectEx@16'
```

I'm using MinGW and i'm linking my application with the following libs:

```
-lws2_32 -lwsock32 -lmswsock
```

On msdn says that the minimum version required for this function is Windows XP or Windows Server 2003, so i defined WINVER with 0x0502, but i still get the same error.

What i'm missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you apparently missed is this note in the MSDN documentation for the [`DisconnectEx()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737757.aspx):

> **Note:** The function pointer for the `DisconnectEx` function must be
>   obtained at run time by making a call to the `WSAIoctl` function with
>   the `SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER` opcode specified. The input
>   buffer passed to the `WSAIoctl` function must contain
>   `WSAID_DISCONNECTEX`, a globally unique identifier (GUID) whose value
>   identifies the `DisconnectEx` extension function. On success, the
>   output returned by the `WSAIoctl` function contains a pointer to the
>   `DisconnectEx` function. The `WSAID_DISCONNECTEX` GUID is defined in
>   the `Mswsock.h` header file.

Note that the MSDN documentation for `DisconnectEx()` doesn't specify a library under the Requirements section. That implies that you have to load this function dynamically at runtime via the [`WSAIoctl()`function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741621.aspx) to obtain a function pointer.

Comment: Yes, my bad, i missed that... at 3:30 am it's hard to keep the eyes opened hehe. Thanks.

Comment: @Leandro F. Vaz: No problem. It's just a friendly reminder to really read through the documentation. :-)